# How to compare two json data using php one is xml other one is mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, json, xml, laravel

I do have two json multidimensional array one is from database and other is from my public path it comes as xml, How do i compare both data are same or not?

one data coming from database,

```
     $shipment = Shipment::take('10')->get()->toJson();
     $ship =  json_decode($shipment,TRUE);
```

other data coming from local storage as xml files,

```
      $files = File::get(storage_path('xml\Last_FILSDCSEA.xml'));      
      $xml = simplexml_load_string($files, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
      $json = json_encode($xml);
      //dd($json);
      $data = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

and comparison something below,

```
   if(($ship['JS_UniqueConsignRef']) == ($data['JS_UniqueConsignRef']))
    {

        $difference = array_diff_assoc($ship,$data);
        dd($difference);
    }
```

any changes have to made over this code please help?

Comment: what are these two json look like

Comment: It also contain multidimensional array with multiple datas.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use `array_diff` and by using it you can make sure they match exactly the content in the JSON structure.

```
$ship = json_decode($shipment, TRUE);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$array_result = array_diff($ship,$data);

if(empty($array_result[0])) {     
    echo "they are same";
}
```

Comment: Depending on the data structure as *This function only checks one dimension of a n-dimensional array*

Comment: I try both of that but problem i can't compare entire data because it has too much data.                                                                            
    if(($sh['JS_UniqueConsignRef']) == ($da['JS_UniqueConsignRef']))
        {

            $difference = array_diff_assoc($ship,$data);
            dd($difference);
        }

Comment: @munazzil This is the way I have solved in the past.